# Override the destination of ons-back-button

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I have a page in my mobile app where I have a segment control with 6 options. I want the user to be able to click any of those options and see that content. The problem is, I don't want the user to have to click the back button multiple times to go back through the pages. Is there a way to override the location the back button will navigate to? I'm using OnsenUI/

```
<div class="navigation-bar bar">
  <div class="navigation-bar__center">
      <div class="button-bar">
        <div class="button-bar__item">
            <input type="radio" name="navi-segment-a" checked>
            <div class="button-bar__button">
                <div class="animated fadeIn">1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="button-bar__item">
            <input type="radio" name="navi-segment-a">
            <div class="button-bar__button">
                <div class="animated fadeIn">2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
      </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I've changed the way I'm going about this. However, I'm now faced with a new but similar problem. I have 6 links at the top of my view. Each links to the same view, but with a different parameter in order to change the data displayed. The problem is, if the user clicks through n screens, when they click the back button, it goes back through each screen. I want to override that ons-back-button action to go to a specific view (#/thispage/thisview).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using version 2, the following documents will aid you:

https://onsen.io/v2/docs/js/ons.html#method-setDefaultDeviceBackButtonListener

This is commonly utilized like this:

```
ons.ready(function () {
    ons.disableDeviceBackButtonHandler();
    document.addEventListener('backbutton', function () {}, false);
});
```

Feel free to put in the empty function whatever code you want or a call to your navigation function.

Comment: I am not using 2.x

Comment: It helps a lot if you specify your platform in your question because there are multiple versions now.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an ons-tab-bar (or create something like it) and change its style to create your 6 segment option?

https://onsen.io/v2/docs/js/ons-tabbar.html